# Many 'group by' webparts intermittent loading

Tags: web-part, ajax

I have several list webparts (7-8) that all have documents that are "grouped by" a single field. The problem I'm having is that the expand button will sit at "Loading" and won't load! Some load quickly, others don't load at all. Whats the deal?

[image]

Comment: It is probably some ajax not loading correctly.  I would suggest starting with Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to help identify what might not be loading correctly between your browser and the server.

Comment: I couldn't find where the ajax wasn't loaded correctly. Trouble is in Firefox, most of them load fine. In IE, its having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by deleting and readding the webparts. The problematic webparts were due to a post migration of ListWebPart type that was stuck in an old version. Deleting that old version and readding the new version of the webpart made it load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If "Fiscal Year" is a calculated field, change the 'data type returned' of the calculated field from "Date and Time" to "Single Line of Text".  The problem in this situation is that it is requesting data for a Date object but only providing the year, which naturally does not match a fully-formed DateTime.  Changing it to text makes it query the data for an exact match which should produce the results you are looking for.

Comment: The Fiscal Year datatype is all Single Line of Text.

Comment: If that is the case, you might want to check your patch level.  One of the Cumulative Updates between June 2011 and Feb 2012 resolved this on one of the lists where we saw this

Comment: Our Patch Level is CU Oct 2011, so that might explain something, but which one is the one I need?

Comment: The Official Microsoft answer is to only apply the CU that contains fixes to issues that you are seeing.  The real-world answer is to apply the most recent CU so that it can correct issues that may be present but have not yet been reported to your internal help desk yet.  The most recent is the April 2012 Cumulative Update - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff800847

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

1. Collapse **all** the groups with the "Loading ..." indicator
2. Press F5 key to refresh
3. Expand one group

I have a lot of views in several Site Collections with this erroneous behavior (and hundreds without it) and this work around, even when is annoying, works ok.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Expand one Group
2. Refresh with F5
3. "Loading ..." forever